# MongoDB get count of particular key in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

In mongoDB, how can we get the count of particular key in an array

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("52d9212608a224e99676d378"),
 "business" : [
  {
   "name" : "abc",
   "rating" : 4.5
  },
  {
   "name" : "pqr"
  },
  {
   "name" : "xyz",
   "rating" : 3.6
  }
 ]
}
```

in the above example, business is an array (with "name" and/or "rating" keys)

How can i get the count of business array with only "rating" key existing ?

Expected output is : 2

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have to use [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). In particular you need to [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) your array, then match only elements with `rating` field included, then [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) documents back to original format.

Try something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $match: { /* your query criteria document */ } },
    { $unwind: "$business" },
    { $match: {
        "business.rating": { $exists: 1 }
      }
    },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        business: { $push: "$business" },
        business_count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
])
```

Result will look like the following:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("52d9212608a224e99676d378"),
  business: [
    { name: "abc", rating: 4.5 },
    { name: "xyz", rating: 3.6 }
  ],
  business_count: 2
}
```

**UPD** Looks like OP doesn't want to group results by wrapping document `_id` field. Unfortunately `$group` expression must specify `_id` value, otherwise it fails with exception. But, this value can actually be constant (e.g. plain `null` or `'foobar'`) so there will be only one resulting group with collection-wise aggregation.

Comment: I like your code sample (and it works, so +1). In the future, please use the `test` database (not `foo`) so we can save typing and editing in the mongo shell.... and SO comments ;)

Comment: @ixe013 OK ;) BTW `foo` is not a database name here - it's a collection name. And collection `test` does not have any special meaning (unlike `test` database which is the default one in mongo shell).

Comment: Yes, collection. When I read the question, I created the OP document in the default `test` collection. No biggie, I guess I'm just grumpy this morning after a short night!

Comment: I like the solution. But to filter out documents that do not have rating key in any element of business array I would add "{ $match : { business : { $elemMatch : { rating : { $exists : true } } } } }" **before** $unwind pipe. See [Early filtering](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#early-filtering)

Comment: @user3195726 Great suggestion! It's a kind of optimization though, and I am just showing the general technique here. So let's keep this as a comment.

Comment: @vbo: your answer is helpful, but i just need the count instead of object returned.    
if i have multiple docs, i wanted to know how many businesses have ratings.
i will try that

Comment: @StephenTalari `business_count: { $sum: 1 }` - this is for counting, and `business: { $push: "$business" }` is for collecting documents to the array. If you want to count businesses, not wrapping documents you need to add another `$group` to the end. Just like the current last `$group` just without without `_id` grouping. Try this out and get back to me if you need some clarification.

Comment: I suggest you to play around with the aggregation pipeline in general and my query in particular to get used to it.